# Generating a 10 digit random confirmation string php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a 'confirmation code' for every user account created on my website and storing it in the db along with their personal information. As you can see in the example below, I tried to generate a random string factoring in the time variable, however, the string is unneccessarily long.

I would like the string to be shorter than the one produced by `md5` I was wondering if there is a relatively easy way to generate 10 digit (max) alphanumeric string that has an extremely low collision rate?

What I tried:

```
  md5(mt_rand(10000,99999).time() . 'example@domain.com');
```

Output:

```
0dd6854dba19e70cfda0ab91595e0376
```

Comment: Why are you concerned with the length of the string?  What's wrong with a longer string?

Comment: If a user needs help with their account and I ask for their confirmation number, it would be easier to not have a 30+ character string, especially if they got 1 character wrong...

Comment: @MHZ: I guess you could just use your existing MD5 string, and take the first 10 chars?

Comment: @houbysoft I thought about that:) Not sure if that is the best solution though...

Comment: @MHZ: see my answer for another solution, using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`.

Comment: I'd take the first 10 chars of `md5()`. Good hash functions such as this ripple even a small change in input throughout the whole of its output, so your collision rate is effectively 1/2^40; that's pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP provides the [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function that can be made to securely do what you want.

Do something like:

```
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(5))
```

The above will give you something like `e9d196aa14`, for example.

Alternatively, just take the first 10 chars of your existing MD5 string.

Comment: This method is pretty nice. Thanks for the help! I am trying to decide if I should go with the first 10 characters of the long string generated in my initial post, or this method...

Comment: @MHZ This is technically probably the most correct answer, but might be overkill for non-cryptographic use. Since you aren't basing security on the hash code, taking the first ten characters of MD5 is probably fine.

Comment: Overkill in what sense? It creates a relatively short random string with negligibly low collision rates, right? Wouldn't I be better off with this method? Considering it accomplishes the task with less code:)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

+

http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

This will generate you any random output string from `Aa-Zz` and `0-9` characters.

```
function genString($length) {
    $lowercase = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    $uppercase = "ASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMQWERTYUIOP";
    $numbers = "1234567890";
    $specialcharacters = "{}[];:,./<>?_+~!@#";
    $randomCode = "";
    mt_srand(crc32(microtime()));
    $max = strlen($lowercase) - 1;
    for ($x = 0; $x < abs($length/3); $x++) {
        $randomCode .= $lowercase{mt_rand(0, $max)};
    }
    $max = strlen($uppercase) - 1;
    for ($x = 0; $x < abs($length/3); $x++) {
        $randomCode .= $uppercase{mt_rand(0, $max)};
    }
    $max = strlen($specialcharacters) - 1;
    for ($x = 0; $x < abs($length/3); $x++) {
        $randomCode .= $specialcharacters{mt_rand(0, $max)};
    }
    $max = strlen($numbers) - 1;
    for ($x = 0; $x < abs($length/3); $x++) {
        $randomCode .= $numbers{mt_rand(0, $max)};
    }
    return str_shuffle($randomCode);
}
```

Usage

```
$str = genString(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is

```
$random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10); // you can increase the digits by changing 10 to desired digit
```

Please check it out

Answer (score -1):

Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: How is this relvant or useful? :)

Comment: You could do something similar to `$short = str_split($long,10);` then get the first value in array $short. Of course, you could use somebody else's suggestion. :)